# Convert Viewport point to container reference point in WPF

Tags: wpf, viewport, point, mouse-coordinates

I have plotted controls on ViewPort at specified locations.  And the ViewPort is placed on Canvas.
On click on the plotted control, I want to get the coordinate point with reference to the ViewPort container(Canvas). I get the point coordinate where the control placed on ViewPot, but I want it with reference to the container.

Please suggest your ideas for converting the ViewPort Point to normal screen point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got:

var currentPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(container);

This will return current click point with reference to ViewPort.